# Parsing XML sheet with Rails Nokogiri XPath for attributes and elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I'm trying to use Nokogiri in a rails 4.2.0 environment to parse a data sheet of classes.  What I intend is to have each course parsed, with the @catalog_nbr, @subject attributes stored, as well as the first instructor listed.  The code I have below simply yields empty arrays.  I believe the problem has to do with using the .each method, but I can't figure it out!

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML( open("https://courseroster.reg.cornell.edu/courses/roster/SP15/CS/xml/") )
doc.xpath("//course").each do
  num = doc.xpath("./@catalog_nbr").text
  subject = doc.xpath("./@subject").text
  instructor = doc.xpath("./sections/section/meeting/instructors/instructor")[1].text
  Course.create(:subject => subject, :number => num, :instructor => instructor)
end
```

Comment: You ought to be using `Nokogiri.XML()` instead of `Nokogiri.HTML()`. The former treats the XML as XML; the latter treats the XML as HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution. Note that the XML file you have linked to always has both catalog numbers and subjects for each course, so there's no need for any `|| "N/A"` there (but perhaps it's nice to be safe):

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri.XML( open("https://courseroster.reg.cornell.edu/courses/roster/SP15/CS/xml/") )
doc.xpath("/courses/course").each do |course|
  num  = course["catalog_nbr"] || "N/A"  # in case it doesn't exist
  subj = course["subject"]     || "N/A"  # in case it doesn't exist
  inst = (course.at("sections/section/meeting/instructors/instructor/text()") || "N/A").to_s
  data = { subject:subj, number:num, instructor:inst }
  p data
end

#=> {:subject=>"CS", :number=>"1110", :instructor=>"Van Loan,C (cfv3)"}
#=> {:subject=>"CS", :number=>"1112", :instructor=>"Fan,K (kdf4)"}
#=> {:subject=>"CS", :number=>"1130", :instructor=>"Frey,C (ccf27)"}
#=> {:subject=>"CS", :number=>"1130", :instructor=>"Frey,C (ccf27)"}
#=> {:subject=>"CS", :number=>"1132", :instructor=>"Fan,K (kdf4)"}
#=> etc.
```

Comment: Hi, this was a great solution.  However, I'm not familiar with the syntax of 'p data' and it wasn't storing the data in the database.  When I used Course.create(:subject => subj, :number => num, :instructor => inst) instead, it worked!

Comment: FWIW `p data` calls the [`Kernel#p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-p) method, printing out a "debugging" version of the value (as shown at the bottom of my answer). Because I don't have a database set up to match yours, or your models, I chose to show you that you had the data you needed, and you could just do: `Course.create( data )` if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.
After selecting the doc, we need to traverse each of the rows in the document. Lets call each of that rows as `row`
Next. Assign default values if they are blank. Read this [article](http://rors.org/2008/03/19/self-or-default-if-empty-dry-way) to get more information on this.

```
doc.xpath("//course").each do |row|
  num = row.xpath("./@catalog_nbr").text  || "N/A"
  subject = row.xpath("./@subject").text || "N/A"
  instructor = row.xpath("./sections/section/meeting/instructors/instructor")[1].text  || "N/A"
  Course.create(:subject => subject, :number => num, :instructor => instructor)
end
```

Comment: That seems to work well!  However, on the instructor line, the application fails when there is an empty instructor field.